# How to give name to response model on AWS API Gateway in OpenApi specification

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We are using AWS API gateway for our OpenAPI specifications. We are also using API-first approach with OpenAPI spec embedded in our SAM templates.

Everything works perfectly until the point when we deploy our API into API gateway. All models that are created from responses are re-named using some random generator. This causes us a lot of pain, because we cannot download exported API from API gateway and give it to our teams just because this is not deterministic and it changes every time.

Is there any way to force AWS API gateway to respect response name in generated model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the name with `title` property.
https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.1#schema-object

```
definitions:
  Pet:
    title: Pet
    required:
      - name
      - petType # required for inheritance to work
    properties:
      name: 
        type: string
      petType:
        type: string
    discriminator:
      propertyName: petType
      x-discriminator-value: Pet
  Cat:
    title: Cat
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet' # Cat has all properties of a Pet
      - properties: # extra properties only for cats
          huntingSkill:
            type: string
            default: lazy
            enum:
              - lazy
              - aggressive
  Dog:
    title: Dog
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet' # Dog has all properties of a Pet
      - properties: # extra properties only for dogs
          packSize:
            description: The size of the pack the dog is from
            type: integer
```

If that doesn't work for you, then try `x-discriminator-value` ([ref](https://docs.apimatic.io/specification-extensions/swagger-codegen-extensions/#discriminator-value-extension)).

Comment: "title" parameter is not working. All the request and response models still have random names like "MODEL1a2s3d"